# Affirmative form of "He has no right to question." while preserving the meaning

Tags: negation, homework

> He has no right to question.

What would this sentence be if we were to make it affirmative.
This question appeared in an exam. I tried

> It is unlawful for him to question.

but the answer given was

> He has hardly any right to question.

Now "hardly any" implies "some" so this alters the meaning of the sentence.

What would be the answer while preserving the meaning as accurately as possible?

Comment: Your question lacks precision. So you are looking for a single verb that means not to have something, not to possess it?

Comment: Yes, any alternative sentence that preserves the meaning of the original but doesn't have negatives like 'no', 'not', etc in it.

Comment: A non-negative version of a negative sentence **does** change the meaning. This is not a transformation like the Passive; this is a completely different sentence with a different meaning. In particular, the opposite of _have no right to question_ is _have a_ (or _the_) _right to question_, and it does alter the meaning.

Comment: @JohnLawler Is it clearer now?

Comment: @user80551 I wouldn't go so far as to say that *hardly any* is synonymous with *some*. It's more like *barely* or *almost no discernible amount*, which one might say if said *right* was not etched in stone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might object to "unlawful" as it introduces a new piece of information; the original sentence doesn't specify whether the right is legal, moral, contractual or anything else, while "unlawful" means "he has no legal right".

But that said, I think it's a reasonable enough answer, as there won't really be a perfect answer, and it is clearer in its denying "him" a right than the answer given, for the reasons you say.

Andrew's answer introduces some new verbs which are superior to your "unlawful" because they similarly don't restrict to a particular type of right.

One could also try:

> He lacks any right to question.

This keeps closer to the form of the original negative case, the one advantage of the "hardly any" answer, but is also more absolute.

Comment: Seems to me that this is the best but I'll wait for some time before accepting.

Comment: There are two usages that immediately spring to mind for the original affirmative: 'He has no right to question.' (unmarked statement of fact) and He has **no right** to question! (emphatic and emotive). I'd use 'He has the right to question.' as the opposite of the first, but 'He has **every** right to question!' as the opposite of the second.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I think you are misunderstanding the asker’s intention. It seems the aim is to come up with a sentence that has the same meaning as ‘has no right to question’, but does not contain a negation; rather than a sentence that is the affirmative opposite of ‘has no right to question’.

Comment: *Lacks* is kind of negative, no? Otherwise, I definitely agree regardless that *unlawful* changes the meaning significantly and has more limited applications than the other choices.

Comment: @JohnQPublic it's not using grammatical negation. We would not consider "doesn't lack" to be a double negative, for example.

Comment: @JonHanna Perhaps I misinterpreted then. I'd assumed the asker was looking for a sentence that was entirely positive. Upon rereading, your example is fine. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a verb like *prohibit,* or *bar, ban* and the like: these have a disabling effect without using a real negative indicator.

> He is prohibited from questioning.
>   He is barred from questioning.
>   He is banned from questioning.

Probably the best similar synonym for *having no right* is *being disbarred,* but the *dis-* may render that unsuitable.

Note that the *to* in the original becomes *from* in the reversed sentence, which may also help in finding suitable verbs.